# Stop wordpress PHP curl requests from happening twice

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, woocommerce

I am trying to track user activity with Customer.io on my site. I am sending curl requests with user info, page views and triggered events (purchases). For some reason the curl requests are being sent out twice.

I have the below bit of code in my footer.php file. (purchase curl req is not shown as its in a different file).

```
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

if ($current_user instanceof WP_User) {

    $userId = $current_user->ID;
    $userEmail = $current_user->user_email;
    $userRegisterDate = strtotime($current_user->user_registered);
    $userFirstName = $current_user->user_firstname;

    if (($userId && $userEmail && $userRegisterDate && $userFirstName)) {
        $session = curl_init();

        $customer_id = $userId; 
        $customerio_url = 'https://track.customer.io/api/v1/customers/';
        $site_id = 'xxxxxxxx';
        $api_key = 'xxxxxxxx';

        $data = array('email' => $userEmail, 'first_name' => $userFirstName, 'created_at' => $userRegisterDate);

        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, $customerio_url . $customer_id);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $site_id . ':' . $api_key);

        curl_exec($session);
        curl_close($session);

        $session = curl_init();
        $customerio_url = 'https://track.customer.io/api/v1/customers/' . $customer_id . '/events';
        $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

        $data = array('name' => $actual_link, 'type' => 'page', 'data[referrer]' => 'http://www.spanishvirtually.com');

        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, $customerio_url);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $site_id . ':' . $api_key);

        curl_exec($session);
        curl_close($session);
    }
}
?>
```

When I check my activity log in customer.io, all of the page event views are duplicated. It seems that the curl requests are being sent out twice. I am assuming that the footer.php page is loading/being called twice.

How can I prevent that from happening?

I also have similar code in a custom woocommerce template file (theme/woocommerce/checkout/thankyou.php and it too is sending the curl request twice)

Comment: I'd assume you're calling this page twice.  Try dropping a mail statement at the top of this page then calling it and see if you get two mails

Comment: Yup. I got two emails

Comment: So you need to go up a level and figure out where this page is being included from, but we're not going to be able to figure that out by looking at this page :)

Comment: It's the footer.php in the root dir of my theme

Comment: Do you need to run it on every page load? or can you attach it to a specific `do_action` hook? Though if your page is loading twice, that may not resolve anything. I'd suggest testing in another theme and/or disabling other plugins to see if you can find the root cause.

Comment: For the page views/activity tracking it would have to be on each page load but the event of purchasing something could be attached to the "confirm purchase" button thats a good idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't standard behavior, but you can stop it by wrapping the code in a statement to see if it's already ran.

```
if (!defined('TRACK_CUSTOMER')) {
    define('TRACK_CUSTOMER', 1);

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ($current_user instanceof WP_User) {
        // ...
}
```

Comment: A nice workaround for his double page loading issue.

Comment: Seems like this would work but it's still loading up twice

```if (!defined('TRACK_CUSTOMER')) {
        define('TRACK_CUSTOMER', 1);

        mail("myemail@example.com", "test", "only once please");
    }```